# Hide certain buttons based on certain matches

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anyway to hide certain button if matches a rule as follows?
The below is code used to create the button column and the code to get matches.

I tried BookButtonCell.Visible = false;, but it says it is only readonly.

Thanks.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {          
            DataGridViewButtonColumn bookbutton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            {
                bookbutton.HeaderText = "Book";
                bookbutton.Text = "Book";
                bookbutton.Name = "Book";
                bookbutton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            }
            readalleventsdataGridView.Columns.Add(bookbutton); 


                int x = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in readalleventsdataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell BookButtonCell = gridRow.Cells["Book"];
                    DataGridViewCell EndDateCell = gridRow.Cells["EndDate"];
                    String StrTodayDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
                    DateTime TodayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StrTodayDate);
                    String StrEndDate = EndDateCell.Value.ToString();
                    DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StrEndDate);
                    int result = DateTime.Compare(EndDate, TodayDate);
                    if (result < 0)
                        {
                          What Commands To Hide The Button?
                        }
                        x++;
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourButton.Visible=false, which will hide the button from displaying
```

you can try like this

```
 if (result < 0)
{
  BookButtonCell.Visible=false;
}
```

Edit : for your Gridview you can check this [Disable Button in Gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx)

Comment: I tried BookButtonCell.Visible = false;, but it says it is only readonly.

Comment: I had read through the post in msdn, however, I am seeking a shorter method as the msdn is showing a long list of codes to disable a button. Thanks alot.

Comment: This doesn't work at all and needs to be removed as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

The [DataGridViewButtonColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncell.aspx) [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.visible.aspx) Property is a ReadOnly Property.

Even though it looks like a button, it is still a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, with the same rules for visibility that one would have. So the short of it is that you will need to do something like Ravi suggests or handle the [DataGridView.CellContentClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx) Event testing wether or not the Button is supposed to be active and swallowing the event if it is not.

From above link:

> This property indicates whether the cell is in a **row** or a **column** with
>   its Visible property set to false.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `.Visible` property, which can be set to `false`.

Comment: I tried BookButtonCell.Visible = false;, but it says it is only readonly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `visible` property as others have already written. But there is a simple trick, which I found today and gave as an answer on another post on the same topic (the other one is actually a duplicate of this):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29010384/2505186
Summary:
Assign a different `DataGridViewCellStyle` to those cells, where the style has its `padding` property left value set to a value higher than the column width.
This causes the button to be shifted out of the visible area of the cell. :-)

Answer (score 0):

as you know you cannot change the visible of a datagridview cell .

you must disable row or column . if you draw it in your mind you will see it isnt good look if a gridviewcell be invisible.

so visible is read only property for datagridviewcell
use this code

```
DataGridViewButtonCell dgvbc = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
            dgvbc.ReadOnly = true;
```

another way is change the foreground or background of the cell to a color that user understand cant use that :)

atleast with this code you can disable the butoon.