# Click handler for a disabled control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is the a way for a ClickHandler to work IF the control is `Enabled = False`? Like for example to show a messagebox with the message "Unable to change this data".

Comment: Windows Forms? ASP.Net Web Forms? WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: Enabled = false means "disable the click event".  Displaying a message box to tell the user what she already knows isn't typically useful, but you'd need to leave Enabled to true and somehow otherwise give an indication that clicking doesn't do anything useful.  In general, do reserve a message box for "Eek!  Something bad happened!" kind of messages.  You don't want to wear the user out and get her in auto-click mode when you *do* have something important to tell.

Comment: The control is a DataGridView, and it looks same both enabled and disabled.

Comment: Perhaps you could change the background color or alter the look in some other way when you disable it.  It would seem to me that something like that would be better than a message box.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer's link in this so question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467878/hide-certain-buttons-based-on-certain-matches/10468576#10468576

Comment: Thanks Mark, good idea! I'll go for that!

Answer (score 0):

quickest way: cover it with a 0% opacity Panel with an OnClick handler, panel1.Width = btn1.Width, Height, Location.

Comment: Panel doesn't support opacity.

Answer (score 0):

In many instances, such as text fields, consider making them readonly instead of disabled

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used a `Panel` control behind a disabled `Button`. The `Panel` receives the click event when the button is disabled but not when the button is enabled.